# Как сделать get запрос с выборкой по id?

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

Всем привет! Мне необходимо обращаться к серверу для обновления данных в корзине. И соответственно мне не нужны все товары, а лишь те, которые в ней лежат. Есть задумка, что нужно пробежаться циклом по массиву данных и взять те, у которых совпадает id? Только можно ли использовать цикл в запросе? Нигде не нашла информацию об этом. Как это правильно делается?

Comment: выбираете все id в цикле, а потом делаете запрос с передачей этих всех id на сервер. всё

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно принять все данные и обработать их перебирая циклом нужные id.
Если вы имеете возможность изменять код сервера, то сортировку по id можете выполнить там, просто отправив массив нужных id и перебор выполнять непосредственно на сервере.

Писать http запросы внутри цикла плохая затея.

Если api не ваш, то изучите его. Возможно там уже реализована сортировка, тогда вам нужно отправить массив id.

Comment: спасибо, так и сделала

Comment: как сделать в строке запроса уникальные названия id?
сейчас у меня передается такой строкой, но это неправильно, названия параметров не уникальны
URL?id=2&id=1&id=5

Comment: Это не правильно. У вас ключ переменной query должен быть уникальный. Сервер не сможет обработать все эти переменные с одним названием. Вы уверены, что все данные нужно передавать с помощью query string? Я не смогу вам помочь, пока не знаю как должен принимать сервер данные. Отправьте документацию по вашему запросу. Может быть он в body все данные принимает.

Comment: Массив в json должен примерно выглядеть так: {id:[{n:1,n:2,n:3}]}